# How to use slugify in Python 3?

Tags: python, slugify

I'm trying to use [slugify](https://github.com/un33k/python-slugify), which I installed using `pip3 install slugify`. However, in the interpreter, if I try to slugify the string `'hello'` I see the following:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: from slugify import slugify

In [2]: slugify('hello')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-a58110f37579> in <module>()
----> 1 slugify('hello')

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/slugify.py in slugify(string)
     22 
     23     return re.sub(r'[-\s]+', '-',
---> 24             unicode(
     25                 re.sub(r'[^\w\s-]', '',
     26                     unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', string)

NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined

In [3]: slugify(u'hello')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-acc9f7b8d41e> in <module>()
----> 1 slugify(u'hello')

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/slugify.py in slugify(string)
     22 
     23     return re.sub(r'[-\s]+', '-',
---> 24             unicode(
     25                 re.sub(r'[^\w\s-]', '',
     26                     unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', string)

NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined
```

By contrast, in Python 2 the latter does work:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.4.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: from slugify import slugify

In [2]: slugify(u'hello')
Out[2]: u'hello'
```

How can I get this to work in Python 3?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The [slugify package you installed](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slugify) isn't built for python 3, it currently only supports python 2. And it is very unlikely it will get updated. One of the easiest way to tell is that throughout its source code, it used the python 2 keyword `unicode` in which it doesn't exist in python 3.

You probably did:

```
pip install slugify
```

That was an outdated package, not the one you linked.

To install the slugify package you linked, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-slugify, it's called `python-slugify` when you install it, it supports all recent python versions. And have way more functionalities.

```
pip install python-slugify
```

And import the same way as the other package:

```
from slugify import slugify
```

Note: **YOU MUST DELETE THE ORIGINAL PACKAGE YOU INSTALLED**, since they uses the same name.

Comment: Just a note - delete the original package: `pip uninstall slugify`. It may require also restarting the environment (e.g., I needed to restart Atom with Hydrogen)

Comment: Could that slugify somehow be updated from python-slugify to avoid such confusion again?

Answer (score 1):

install python-slugify

`pip install python-slugify`